# ScalaQuery not creating DDL?

Tags: scala, scalaquery

I have an example DB in a scala object, but the tables are not created.

If I call the initialize and then I call the addEntries, I get a Table not existing exception by the JDBC layer. Where am I wrong?

```
object ExampleCompanyH2TestDb {
    val Companies = new Table[(Int, Int, String, String, String, Double,Double)]("COMPANIES") {

       def id = column[Int]("COMPANY_ID", O.PrimaryKey)

       // This is the primary key column
       def id2 = column[Int]("COMPANY_ID2")

       def name = column[String]("COMPANY_NAME")

       def country = column[String]("COUNTRY")

       def city = column[String]("CITY")

       def latitude = column[Double]("LATITUDE")

       def longitude = column[Double]("LONGITUDE")


       // Every table needs a * projection with the same type as the
       table's type parameter
       def * = id ~ id2 ~ name ~ country ~ city ~ latitude ~ longitude
   }
// Connect to the database and execute the following block within a session


val db = Database.forURL("jdbc:h2:mem:test1", driver = "org.h2.Driver")

def initialize = {
    db withSession {
        // The session is never named explicitly. It is bound to the current
       // thread as the threadLocalSession that we imported
         (Companies.ddl).create

    }
}

// Create the tables, including primary and foreign keys
def addEntries(entries: Iterable[ExampleCompany]) {
   val asTuples = entries.map {
     ExampleCompany.unapply
   }.collect {
     case Some(entry) => entry
   }.toSeq
    db withSession {
      Companies.insertAll(asTuples: _*)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem: the h2 in memory driver does not store data among the session, unless:

jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1.

is specified

(See http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html)